# How to replace the number with forward slash to square square brackets in python

Tags: python, regex, replace

```py
input = '/topology/1/deviceGroup/1/ethernet/1/ipv4/1'
output = '/topology[1]/deviceGroup[1]/ethernet[1]/ipv4[1]'

output = input.replace('\/[0-9]\/ + \/[0-9]', [[^0-9]])
```

But I am not getting the exact regex to do the replacement in python, please help.

Comment: Do not use `input` as variable name, you're shadowing built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> inp = '/topology/1/deviceGroup/1/ethernet/1/ipv4/1'
>>> re.sub(r'/(\d+)', r'[\1]', inp)
'/topology[1]/deviceGroup[1]/ethernet[1]/ipv4[1]'
```

Comment: where 1 is integer it can vary up to 2digits , its not constant, thank you its working